# ssml in Dialogflow webhook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, webhooks, dialogflow-es

**This is not a duplicate question, I didn't get the exact response so raised a new question here..**

Getting an issue while writing ssml tags in the webhook response.

Earlier my webhook response:

`{fulfillmentText: 'Amount for Invoice : TEST is $300'}` - it is working fine with all the interfaces i.e. Web, Google Assistant

now I want to use ssml, so I tried updating the response in webhook to

`{"speech":"<speak>Amount for Invoice : TEST is $300<speak>","displayText":"Listen Voice.."}`

This is erroring out in the Dialogflow side as I think it is not able to read the response.
Any help?

Note: I am using Google Cloud Function to send the response back to Dialogflow engine:

`res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'fulfillmentText': output }));`

Comment: https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-ssml-nodejs ?

Comment: Yes, checked that but is it working fine? there should be some direct function as in Alexa where you can directly type ssml or text and it will parse the response accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should change **speech** key in json to **ssml**.
See example below [(source)](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json/blob/master/responses/v2/ActionsOnGoogle/RichResponses/SimpleResponseSsml.json):

```
{  
   "payload":{  
      "google":{  
         "expectUserResponse":true,
         "richResponse":{  
            "items":[  
               {  
                  "simpleResponse":{  
                     "ssml":"<speak>Here are <say-as interpret-as=\"characters\">SSML</say-as> samples. I can pause <break time=\"3\" />. I can play a sound <audio src=\"https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/alarms/winding_alarm_clock.ogg\">your wave file</audio>. I can speak in cardinals. Your position is <say-as interpret-as=\"cardinal\">10</say-as> in line. Or I can speak in ordinals. You are <say-as interpret-as=\"ordinal\">10</say-as> in line. Or I can even speak in digits. Your position in line is <say-as interpret-as=\"digits\">10</say-as>. I can also substitute phrases, like the <sub alias=\"World Wide Web Consortium\">W3C</sub>. Finally, I can speak a paragraph with two sentences. <p><s>This is sentence one.</s><s>This is sentence two.</s></p></speak>",
                     "displayText":"This is a SSML sample. Make sure your sound is enabled to hear the demo"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```